# Flexbox issue I can't put background video into a background of a box that contains other elements

Tags: html, css, video, flexbox, background

I am desperately trying to do something like this background image https://eggramen.neocities.org/main.html  but I can't achieve it. I want my video to be the size of the container and that the container is inside of the homebox. Currently I can set the width to whatever I want but I can't set the height at all. The video can't go over the other elements in the flexbox. How do I do this?

```css
.homebox_flex{
    border: 2px solid whitesmoke;
    width: 800px;
    height: 800px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: auto;
    padding:10px;
    align-items: center;
    
  }
  .logotext2{
    
    font-size: 20px;
    text-shadow: 4px 4px #000000;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 50px;
    z-index: 5;
  }
  .columns{
    
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
  }
  
  .column {
      flex: 30%;
  }
  .video_container{
    display: absolute;
    background: #7f3197;
    width: 2200px;
    height: 2200px;
    z-index: -5;
  }
  
  
  .backgroundvideo2{
    
    
    
   
  
    
    
  }
  .footer2{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    gap: 30px;
    align-items: center;
    list-style: none;
    z-index: 5;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>asd</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="background2">
        <div class="homebox">
            <div class="homebox_flex">
                <div class="logobox2">
                    <div class="logotext2">
                        <h1 class="titles" id="title3">asd</h1>
                        <h1 class="titles" id="title4">asd</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <ul class="columns">
                    <div class="column">
                        <li>asd</li>
                        <li>asd</li>
                        <li>asd </li>
                        <li>asd </li>
                        <li>asd </li>
                    </div>
                    <div class="column">
                        <li>asd </li>
                        <li>asd </li>
                        <li>asd] </li>
                        <li>asd </li>
                        <li>asd </li>
                    </div>
                    <div class="column">
                        <li>asd</li>
                        <li>asd </li>
                        <li>asd </li>
                        <li>asd </li>
                        <li>asd </li>
                        <li>asd</li>
                    </div>

                </ul>

            </div>
            <ul class="footer2">
                <li class="ft2link">asd</li>
                <li class="ft2link">asd</li>
                <li class="ft2link">asd</li>
                <li class="ft2link">asd</li>
                <li class="ft2link">asd</li>
            </ul>


        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="video_container">
        <div class=""></div>
        <video class="backgroundvideo2" autoplay muted loop src=""></video>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The purple square at the bottom is container for video. The reason why its outside the box is because I tried centering it outside of the flexbox since I thought maybe if I make it so it doesn't conform to flexbox rules I could make it work, but I have no idea what I am doing tbh.

Answer (score 0):

I get known that from your message. you wanted to add a video background inside the container and keep the all content above the video background. So, here is an easy,  flexible & complete solution for you. Please use the HTML & CSS code:

```
<div class="background2">
    <div class="video_container">
        <div class="body_overlay"></div>
        <video autoplay muted loop>
            <source src="https://storage.googleapis.com/coverr-main/mp4/Winter-Grass.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
            <source src="https://storage.googleapis.com/coverr-main/webm/Winter-Grass.webm" type="video/webm" />
        </video>
    </div>
    <div class="homebox">
        <div class="homebox_flex">
            <div class="logobox2">
                <div class="logotext2">
                    <h1 class="titles" id="title3">asd</h1>
                </div>
            </div>

            <ul class="columns">
                <div class="column">
                    <li>asd</li>
                    <li>asd</li>
                    <li>asd</li>
                    <li>asd</li>
                    <li>asd</li>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <li>asd</li>
                    <li>asd</li>
                    <li>asd</li>
                    <li>asd</li>
                    <li>asd</li>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <li>asd</li>
                    <li>asd</li>
                    <li>asd</li>
                    <li>asd</li>
                    <li>asd</li>
                    <li>asd</li>
                </div>
            </ul>

            <ul class="footer2">
                <li class="ft2link">asd</li>
                <li class="ft2link">asd</li>
                <li class="ft2link">asd</li>
                <li class="ft2link">asd</li>
                <li class="ft2link">asd</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.background2 {
  z-index: 1;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 800px;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
}
.video_container {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  background: #000000;
}
.video_container video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
  object-fit: cover;
}
.video_container .body_overlay {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, from(#000000), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)));
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #000000, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3));
  background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, #000000, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3));
}

.homebox_flex {
  height: 800px;
  margin: auto;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  padding: 50px 30px;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.titles {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 72px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  text-shadow: 4px 4px 0 blue;
}

.columns {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.column {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 30%;
  flex: 0 0 30%;
  padding: 30px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
}

.footer2 {
  gap: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  color: #ffffff;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```